# How to remove multiple words start with [ and end with ]

Tags: vim

I have a file subdomains.txt. I want to remove some words from file data.

```
[Sublist3rAPI]    andrei2.markelow.example.com
[Sublist3rAPI]    tema-x.example.com
[ThreatCrowd]     fireeye-testevent.example.com
[ThreatCrowd]     certs.example.com
[Google]     swat.example.com
[Google]     apps.example.com
```

**To**

```
andrei2.markelow.example.com
tema-x.example.com
fireeye-testevent.example.com
certs.example.com
swat.example.com
apps.example.com
```

Comment: With the data shown, you could just do `:%s/.*\s//`

Comment: There are many ways to do that in Vim. Was there a particular problem with what you have tried?

Comment: You could do `gg0dWj.j.j.j.j.`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, You saved me a lot of time. `:%s/.*\s//`

Comment: @mkrieger1 nice movement :-)

Comment: as @mkrieger1 mentioned already, for future questions, please show some research effort - what you have tried to do and didn't work, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using command mode "normal"

```
:%norm dW
```

It applies a normal command `dW`, delete "big word" for the whole file `%`.

or we can filter the current file through awk

```
:%!awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
:%s/^\[\w\+]\s*/
```

or

```
:%s/^\[[^]]\+]\s*/
```